# FDT Templates: set output folder as absolute path

Tags: directory, absolute-path, fdt

When i set the output folder in FDT, this is always REALTIVE to the project folder, even if it has a forward slash...

ex: /Users/paolo/deploy will create the folder in /User/paolo/my_project/Users/paolo/deploy

first.... WHY?????
second: is there a way to set this folder as ABSOLUTE?

many thanx

Answer (score 1):

The reason is to enable multiple developers to develop on the same project. The path is saved in the project. If you share the project via CVS/SVN other developers would need to have the same path. Absolute paths are a bad idea when developing in a team.

I don't know if there is a way to force an absolute path, but I doubt it.

**Edit:**
I remember there was the possibility to attach an ant script to an run configuration to be executed each time the project is build. You might be able to write the ant script such that it copies the output files to an absolute directory.

Comment: thanks arne. i'll dig into ant tasks. btw, we are currently working on team with absolute path without any problem, because we share projects with git but we set to ignore project settings... everyone creates his own project and we share only the code ;)

Comment: Yes, thats a way also. The advantage when sharing project settings also is that new developers get up to speed more quickly because they have to do less to compile/run the whole thing. But that's matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In your launch configuration there is a tab for Ant tasks.  Add a post-compile ant script, here's an example:

```
<project name="copy files">
    <property name="from" value="../bin"/>
    <property name="to" value="/Users/username/deploy>
    <target name="Copy All">
        <copy todir="${to}" >
            <fileset dir="${from}">
                <exclude name="Test.swf"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```